# Allocating memory to a pointer of a data structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory

I have a data structure in C that in the definition, has a series of pointer of different type as:

```
typedef struct data_t{

type_0 *data_0;
...
type_n *data_n;

};
```

Now, suppose I declare a pointer of the same type as *data_t* and allocate memory to that pointer as:

```
data_t *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
```

I have to questions: first, do I need to allocate memory to each pointer inside *data_t*, given that I already allocate for the entire size of *data*?

And if the first is true, then, the allocated memory of each pointer inside *data* has as address inside the range of memory allocated for *data*, or malloc would allocate outside of the range of *data*?

I'm new to C, so maybe my question is non-clear. Let me now how to improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Think in terms of how many "blocks" of memory your program will need. You didn't specify that in your question, so nobody else can answer that for you.  It would be possible for each pointer in the struct to point to a different block of memory; or all point to parts of the same one, or any such combination. It's up to you to decide where and how to allocate the memory for the blocks .

Comment: Each call to `malloc` creates a separate, disjoint block

Comment: @M.M I want to allocate adjoint blocks of memory to the members of my struct.

Comment: In terms of the language standard there is no such thing as "adjoint blocks", operations within one block must stay within the same block. If you intend to have operations that "cross block boundaries" then you would need to allocate one large block instead.

Comment: @M.M I didn't understand you. The only thing I want is that all the information related to my data structure is in adjoint blocks of memory, because I'm doing multilinear algebra and I read that when data is in differents page of memory, like a linked list, its slower than in the same page, so my data structure has as members a double (type) pointer to the values of the array, a size_t pointer of the indices of the array and an int that is the total amount of indices, and I want all that information together.

Comment: I would recommend choosing the simplest solution that works, and then try optimizing it later if necessary. Especially considering your level of experience with the language

Comment: @M.M I already have a functional program that can do all I want. So I thought that it was tiene to optimize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers are exactly what the name implies, they point somewhere else.

When you allocate the memory for the `data` structure object, you allocate space for the pointer *member variables*, but you don't allocate anything for them to point at.

After allocating memory for `data` you need to initialize the member variables, and for the pointer make them point to a valid location.

---

Essentially

```
data_t *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
```

is similar to

```
data_t actual_data_object; // This allocates memory
data_t *data = &actual_data_object;  // Make data point to the allocated memory
```

Would you consider this as allocating memory for where your pointers should point? Hopefully  not. It's the same when you do `malloc`.

Comment: "Hopefully not. "  - I would. Although the standard only uses the term "allocate" for what is usually referred to as "dynamic allocation"

Answer (score 0):

For this example, consider this program instead

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct some_thing
{
    int value;
    int* p_int;
    int argc;
    char** argv;
} Thing;

int main(void) { return 0; }
```

It is better to have something one could compile.

**I will try to write a complete example as I write.**

**Before the questions**

> Now, suppose I declare a pointer of the same type as data_t and allocate memory to that pointer as:

```
        data_t data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
```

Problem here is that you are not doing what you say you are. As your compiler will tell you, you are declaring `data` as a variable of type `data_t`.

In the program:

```
int main(void)
{ 
    struct some_thing one_of = {0}; // ok
    Thing other; // ok
    Thing data = malloc(sizeof(Thing*)); // error [1]
    struct some_thing my_struct = malloc(42); // error [2]
    return 0;
}
```

- [1] error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Thing'
- [2] error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'some_thing'

This is because `data` and `my_struct` are both static. Already allocated by the declaration.

And `malloc()` returns  `void*`, a pointer to `void`.

`malloc` just evaluates the expression in the argument to a value, and then gets from the OS an area with this size and return its address to the caller: `malloc(42)` just returns a pointer to an area of 42 bytes, or `NULL`.

This work:

```
int main(void)
{ 
    struct some_thing one_of = {0};
    Thing other;
    //Thing data = malloc(sizeof(*data)); // error [1]
    //struct some_thing my_struct = malloc(42); // error [2]
    Thing*                       data = malloc(sizeof(Thing*)); // ok
    struct some_thing*           my_struct = malloc(42); // also ok
    return 0;
}
```

as long as the compiler sees it. But lets add to the program:

```
int main(void)
{ 
    struct some_thing one_of = {0};
    Thing other;
    //Thing data = malloc(sizeof(*data)); // error [1]
    //struct some_thing my_struct = malloc(42); // error [2]
    Thing*                       data = malloc(sizeof(Thing*)); // ok
    printf("sizeof(Thing) is %llu, sizeof(Thing*) is %llu\n",
        sizeof(Thing), sizeof(Thing*));
    struct some_thing*           my_struct = malloc(42); // also ok
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
sizeof(Thing) is 32, sizeof(Thing*) is 8
```

And you see that:

- the first `malloc` call gets only 8 bytes and this is less than the size of `Thing` so the program will hopefully oon as you try to use it.
- the second allocates 42 bytes and this is greater than we needed.
- 32 may be an odd number for the size, but note that systems have a default alignment logic, in multiple of some number of bytes. Look for `#pragma` documentation in your compiler.

This is ok:

```
int main(void)
{
   struct some_thing one_of = { 0 };
   Thing other = { 42,NULL,0,NULL };
   Thing* p_thing = malloc(sizeof(Thing)); // ok
   *p_thing = other;
   printf("other.value = %d. In the area pointed"
       " by p_thing value is = %d\n",
       other.value, p_thing->value);
   free(p_thing);
   return 0;
}
```

and shows

```
other.value = 42. In the area pointed by p_thing value is = 42
```

#### now the questions

> first, do I need to allocate memory to each pointer inside data_t, given that I already allocate for the entire size of data?

Yes, you need to allocated memory for each pointer inside the `struct`, or make the pointers point to something valid. `malloc` will just give you an area of some size (can even the 0-size). I will expand the example. And you did not allocated memory for the size of the `struct`.

> the allocated memory of each pointer inside data has as address inside the range of memory allocated for data, or malloc would allocate outside of the range of data?

Outside. The area pointed by a legit call to `malloc` jast just the required size. Has nothing valid inside. You must build it. In the example above is is just the line

```
    *p_thing = other;
```

And it copies just the bits. It is called a *shallow copy* and is very risky when the `struct` has pointers inside it.

#### a complete example

This program builds a `struct` with some diverse fields, including pointers, and shows its contents and then delete it. Note that in general you must check for the success of every call to `malloc`.

#### output

```
 struct contents
    Value: 42
    p_int value: 43
    argc = 2
    [arg 0] = "first one"
    [arg 1] = "other one"
```

#### the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct some_thing
{
    int value;
    int* p_int;
    int argc;
    char** argv;
} Thing;

void so_show(Thing*,const char*); 

int main(void)
{
    const char one[] = "first one";
    const char two[] = "other one";

    Thing* p_thing = malloc(sizeof(Thing)); // ok
    // if we need argv to point to the 2 strings above we need to build it
    // argv must point to an area the size of at least 2 pointers to char
    p_thing->argv = (char**)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
    // and now we point them to some valid data
    p_thing->argv[0] = malloc(1 + strlen(one)); 
    strcpy(p_thing->argv[0], one);
    p_thing->argv[1] = malloc(1 + strlen(two));
    strcpy(p_thing->argv[1], two);

    p_thing->argc = 2;
    // now the value
    p_thing->value = 42;
    // now the pointer needs to point to something
    p_thing->p_int = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(p_thing->p_int) = p_thing->value + 1;

    so_show(p_thing," struct contents\n"); // display it

    // now free is complex...
    free(p_thing->p_int);
    // now the pointers
    free(p_thing->argv[0]);
    free(p_thing->argv[1]);
    // now the vector of pointers
    free(p_thing->argv);
    // now the struct
    free(p_thing);
    return 0;
}

void so_show(Thing* p, const char* msg) {
    if (p == NULL) return;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    Value: %d\n", p->value);
    if ( p->p_int != NULL)
        printf("    p_int value: %d\n", *p->p_int);
    printf("    argc = %d\n", p->argc);
    for( int i = 0; i<p->argc; i+=1)
        printf("    [arg %d] = \"%s\"\n", i, p->argv[i]);
    return;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you wrote "type_t" I'm going to write "form", and wherever you wrote "pointer" I'm going to write "street_address" and wherever you wrote "type_0", I'm going to write "house".

---

I have the concept of a [paper form] ... that in the definition, has a series of lines for writing in [street_addresses] as:

```
typedef struct form_t {
street_address house_0;
...
street_address house_n;
};
```

Now, suppose I ... ask [Mr. malloc] to make space for a [form] somewhere and then give me the [street_address] where the space for it:

```
street_address data = malloc(sizeof(form));
```

I have to questions: first, do I need to [make space] for each [street_address] inside the [form], given that I already received a place to put a [form]?

And if the first is true, then, the allocated [street_address] on the [form] has an address of the [form], or [Mr. Malloc] would [put more forms] at other addresses?

---

Hopefully, this already makes the answers super clear, but lets go over them in detail anyway:

- [Mr.Malloc] has picked out a place with enough space for a [form], and then he gave you the [street_address] of that place.
- There is no [form] yet, because you didn't do anything with that space.
- The (hypothetical) [form] has places to write [street_addresses], but you didn't actually put a [form] there.
- In fact, someone else might have used that place before giving it back to [Mr.Malloc], so you should probably go to the place and put an empty [form] there, and remove whatever was there before your [form].

  - `memset(data, 0, sizeof(data_t));`
- The next thing you'll want to do is ask [Mr.Malloc] to go pick a place to fit a [house], and then give you the [street_address], and then you can write that [street_address] into the [form], so that you don't forget that address.

  - `data->data_0 = malloc(sizeof(type_0));`
- Then you'll want to go *that* place and put an empty [house] there, and remove whatever was there before your [house].

  - `memset(data->data_0, 0, sizeof(type0));`
- When you're done, don't forget to destroy your house, and then tell [Mr.Malloc] that you're done with the place with the [house], so that that place can be used by someone else.

  - `free(data->house_0);`
- After that, don't forget to destroy your form, and then tell [Mr.Malloc] that you're done with that place, so that *that* place can be used by someone else.

  - `free(data);`